# How can I extract the DDL creation table script of a MySql DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, ddl

I am not so into database and I have the following problem.

I have some table on a **MySql** db, how can I export the DDL table definition directly from the MySql console?

Exist some statment to extracts the DDL cration table script from existing table of a DB? Possibly on a file

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question very well, but the MySQL reference [`SELECT ... INTO syntax`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) contains information how to export to a file. ( Or just google "mysql export to file"? )

Comment: Google search "Getting table metadata in MySQL" ?